# How to execute a 1-many mutation in Android?

Tags: android, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS AppSync and Amplify. A snippet of my GraphQL schema look like this:

```
type Inspection @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  date: AWSDate!
  photos: [Photo] @connection(name: "InspectionPhotos")
}

type Photo @model {
  id: ID!
  inspection: Inspection! @connection(name: "InspectionPhotos")
  photo: String!
}
```

EDIT: Here's a snippet of my generated schema:

```
input CreateInspectionInput {
    id: ID
    name: String!
    date: AWSDate!
}

input CreatePhotoInput {
    id: ID
    photo: String!
    photoInspectionId: ID!
}

type Inspection {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    date: AWSDate!
    photos(
        filter: ModelPhotoFilterInput,
        sortDirection: ModelSortDirection,
        limit: Int,
        nextToken: String
    ): ModelPhotoConnection
}

type Photo {
    id: ID!
    inspection: Inspection!
    photo: String!
}

type Mutation {
    createInspection(input: CreateInspectionInput!): Inspection
    updateInspection(input: UpdateInspectionInput!): Inspection
    deleteInspection(input: DeleteInspectionInput!): Inspection
    createPhoto(input: CreatePhotoInput!): Photo
    updatePhoto(input: UpdatePhotoInput!): Photo
    deletePhoto(input: DeletePhotoInput!): Photo
}
```

I want to create a new Photo, so my Input look like this:

```
CreatePhotoInput createPhotoInput = CreatePhotoInput.builder()
                    .photoInspectionId(inspectionId)
                    .photo(getS3Key(localPath))
                    .build();
```

But when creating the mutation below, I get an error that the field `inspection` in `CreatePhotoMutation.CreatePhoto` expects an object of type `CreatePhotoMutation.Inspection`, not a String.

```
final CreatePhotoMutation.CreatePhoto expected =
                new CreatePhotoMutation.CreatePhoto(
                        "Photo",
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                        CreatePhotoInput.photoInspectionId(),
                        CreatePhotoInput.photo());
```

How can I execute this mutation passing only the photoInspectionId?
Am I missing something, since I'm a beginner on Android and AppSync...

Comment: Are you able to create Photos and Inspections the way you would expect in the Queries area in AWS Appsync? https://console.aws.amazon.com/appsync/home

Comment: @ChanceSmith Yes! Using the Queries area in AWS AppSync, I can create a Photo passing the photoInspectionId. I don't know why only in my Android project the mutation expects a object of type CreatePhotoMutation.Inspection instead of String (photoInspectionId)...

Comment: Could you also post your schema so that we can create the API on our side and assist you better? -Rohan

Comment: @RohanDubal I've added the generated schema in my question